# Can't resolve symbol class plus client

Tags: java, android

I used default login activity but after building the app I got two errors in "PlusBaseActivity" cannot resolve symbol class `GooglePlayServicesClient` I changed it to `GoogleApiClient` , but I still get cannot resolve symbol class plus client

that's code below :

```
package net.egy_develop.scci;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;


/**
 * A base class to wrap communication with the Google Play Services PlusClient.
 */
public abstract class PlusBaseActivity extends Activity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = PlusBaseActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // A magic number we will use to know that our sign-in error resolution activity has completed
    private static final int OUR_REQUEST_CODE = 49404;

    // A flag to stop multiple dialogues appearing for the user
    private boolean mAutoResolveOnFail;

    // A flag to track when a connection is already in progress
    public boolean mPlusClientIsConnecting = false;

    // This is the helper object that connects to Google Play Services.
    private PlusClient mPlusClient;

    // The saved result from {@link #onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult)}.  If a connection
    // attempt has been made, this is non-null.
    // If this IS null, then the connect method is still running.
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    /**
     * Called when the {@link PlusClient} revokes access to this app.
     */
    protected abstract void onPlusClientRevokeAccess();

    /**
     * Called when the PlusClient is successfully connected.
     */
    protected abstract void onPlusClientSignIn();

    /**
     * Called when the {@link PlusClient} is disconnected.
     */
    protected abstract void onPlusClientSignOut();

    /**
     * Called when the {@link PlusClient} is blocking the UI.  If you have a progress bar widget,
     * this tells you when to show or hide it.
     */
    protected abstract void onPlusClientBlockingUI(boolean show);

    /**
     * Called when there is a change in connection state.  If you have "Sign in"/ "Connect",
     * "Sign out"/ "Disconnect", or "Revoke access" buttons, this lets you know when their states
     * need to be updated.
     */
    protected abstract void updateConnectButtonState();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initialize the PlusClient connection.
        // Scopes indicate the information about the user your application will be able to access.
        mPlusClient =
                new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this).setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN,
                        Scopes.PLUS_ME).build();
    }

    /**
     * Try to sign in the user.
     */
    public void signIn() {
        if (!mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
            // Show the dialog as we are now signing in.
            setProgressBarVisible(true);
            // Make sure that we will start the resolution (e.g. fire the intent and pop up a
            // dialog for the user) for any errors that come in.
            mAutoResolveOnFail = true;
            // We should always have a connection result ready to resolve,
            // so we can start that process.
            if (mConnectionResult != null) {
                startResolution();
            } else {
                // If we don't have one though, we can start connect in
                // order to retrieve one.
                initiatePlusClientConnect();
            }
        }

        updateConnectButtonState();
    }

    /**
     * Connect the {@link PlusClient} only if a connection isn't already in progress.  This will
     * call back to {@link #onConnected(android.os.Bundle)} or
     * {@link #onConnectionFailed(com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult)}.
     */
    private void initiatePlusClientConnect() {
        if (!mPlusClient.isConnected() && !mPlusClient.isConnecting()) {
            mPlusClient.connect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Disconnect the {@link PlusClient} only if it is connected (otherwise, it can throw an error.)
     * This will call back to {@link #onDisconnected()}.
     */
    private void initiatePlusClientDisconnect() {
        if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
            mPlusClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sign out the user (so they can switch to another account).
     */
    public void signOut() {

        // We only want to sign out if we're connected.
        if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
            // Clear the default account in order to allow the user to potentially choose a
            // different account from the account chooser.
            mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();

            // Disconnect from Google Play Services, then reconnect in order to restart the
            // process from scratch.
            initiatePlusClientDisconnect();

            Log.v(TAG, "Sign out successful!");
        }

        updateConnectButtonState();
    }

    /**
     * Revoke Google+ authorization completely.
     */
    public void revokeAccess() {

        if (mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
            // Clear the default account as in the Sign Out.
            mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();

            // Revoke access to this entire application. This will call back to
            // onAccessRevoked when it is complete, as it needs to reach the Google
            // authentication servers to revoke all tokens.
            mPlusClient.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(new PlusClient.OnAccessRevokedListener() {
                public void onAccessRevoked(ConnectionResult result) {
                    updateConnectButtonState();
                    onPlusClientRevokeAccess();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        initiatePlusClientConnect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        initiatePlusClientDisconnect();
    }

    public boolean isPlusClientConnecting() {
        return mPlusClientIsConnecting;
    }

    private void setProgressBarVisible(boolean flag) {
        mPlusClientIsConnecting = flag;
        onPlusClientBlockingUI(flag);
    }

    /**
     * A helper method to flip the mResolveOnFail flag and start the resolution
     * of the ConnectionResult from the failed connect() call.
     */
    private void startResolution() {
        try {
            // Don't start another resolution now until we have a result from the activity we're
            // about to start.
            mAutoResolveOnFail = false;
            // If we can resolve the error, then call start resolution and pass it an integer tag
            // we can use to track.
            // This means that when we get the onActivityResult callback we'll know it's from
            // being started here.
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, OUR_REQUEST_CODE);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Any problems, just try to connect() again so we get a new ConnectionResult.
            mConnectionResult = null;
            initiatePlusClientConnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * An earlier connection failed, and we're now receiving the result of the resolution attempt
     * by PlusClient.
     *
     * @see #onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        updateConnectButtonState();
        if (requestCode == OUR_REQUEST_CODE && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // If we have a successful result, we will want to be able to resolve any further
            // errors, so turn on resolution with our flag.
            mAutoResolveOnFail = true;
            // If we have a successful result, let's call connect() again. If there are any more
            // errors to resolve we'll get our onConnectionFailed, but if not,
            // we'll get onConnected.
            initiatePlusClientConnect();
        } else if (requestCode == OUR_REQUEST_CODE && responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
            // If we've got an error we can't resolve, we're no longer in the midst of signing
            // in, so we can stop the progress spinner.
            setProgressBarVisible(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Successfully connected (called by PlusClient)
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        updateConnectButtonState();
        setProgressBarVisible(false);
        onPlusClientSignIn();
    }

    /**
     * Successfully disconnected (called by PlusClient)
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        updateConnectButtonState();
        onPlusClientSignOut();
    }

    /**
     * Connection failed for some reason (called by PlusClient)
     * Try and resolve the result.  Failure here is usually not an indication of a serious error,
     * just that the user's input is needed.
     *
     * @see #onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        updateConnectButtonState();

        // Most of the time, the connection will fail with a user resolvable result. We can store
        // that in our mConnectionResult property ready to be used when the user clicks the
        // sign-in button.
        if (result.hasResolution()) {
            mConnectionResult = result;
            if (mAutoResolveOnFail) {
                // This is a local helper function that starts the resolution of the problem,
                // which may be showing the user an account chooser or similar.
                startResolution();
            }
        }
    }

    public PlusClient getPlusClient() {
        return mPlusClient;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I'm on the same boat as you... The changing to the `GoogleApiClient` really tripped me up too... or is still tripping me up... well long story actually but i'm pretty sure I've just about figured it out.

Try changing all the old `PlusClient` code to `GoogleApiClient`; and all the `mPlusClients` code to `mGoogleApiClient`.

I'm currently still testing it out; like 30 or so more minutes and I'll know for sure and I'll get back to you with the answer (Y)

Don't know if you are still looking for an answer but if you are hope this helped... or will help... or whatever anyway cheers.

Check out this link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in